# How would you use しか and ありませんでした together?

Tags: particle-しか

How would you use しか and ありませんでした together?

Comment: How *wouldn't* you?

Answer (score 2):

しか is used along with negative verbs to express "only", in a negative way. In English it could be translated as "nothing but". For example:

> 昨日行ったレストランには、ラーメン**しかありませんでした**。 (There was nothing but ramen at the restaurant we went yesterday).

In many cases, this negative pattern has the nuance that there should be more things beyond that "only" thing expressed with しか. When the speaker says しか, she or he expected to be other things ore more things. In the example above, the speaker would expect that there were available more types of dishes besides ramen, but there was only ramen and not anything else. This feeling of being less than expected is particularly true when using しか with amounts or quantities, such as in:

> 前に住んでいた村は家が4**軒しかありませんでした**。(There were nothing but 4 houses in the village I used to live).

Again, a village with barely 4 houses is way smaller than expected of a village of a regular size, hence the use of しか.

Note that the literal, objective meaning of しか with negative verbs is the same than that of だけ with positive verbs. However だけ does not carry that nuance of "less or fewer" than expected.

> 昨日行ったレストランには、ラーメン**だけありました**。 (There was only ramen at the restaurant we went yesterday).
>
> 前に住んでいた村は家が4**軒だけありました**。 (There were only 4 houses in the village I used to live).

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for a usage example:

> 茄子【なすび】[し]{●}[か]{●}[あ]{●}[り]{●}[ま]{●}[せ]{●}[ん]{●}[で]{●}[し]{●}[た]{●}ので、[ババガヌーシュ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%90%E3%82%AC%E3%83%8C%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5)を作【つく】ることにしました。
>     Since I **didn't have anything but** eggplant, I decided to make [baba ghanoush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baba_ghanoush).

- The ～しか followed by a negative verb means "don't `[VERB]` (any) but/except for ～".
- The ありませんでした just means "there wasn't (any)", or "(someone) didn't have (any)", depending on context.

Another example using しか:

> リンゴ[し]{●}[か]{●}食【た】べませんから便秘【べんぴ】になりました。
>     Since [he] doesn't eat **anything but** apples, [he] got constipated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is なすび more common somewhere? I only ever hear なす (spoken by myself and others) up here in Hokkaido.

Comment: @virmaior, I honestly can't recall where I picked that one up.  I have a dim recollection that it might have been from a friend of mine who grew up in Kōbe, but I'm not certain.  FWIW, I've lived in Iwate, Tochigi, and Tokyo.

Comment: 「なすび」って西日本（関西？）っぽいですよね。（たぶん）

Comment: @virmaior, chocolate -- amusingly, [Nihon Jiten's entry list for なすび](http://www.nihonjiten.com/search/search.php?word=%E3%81%AA%E3%81%99%E3%81%B3) suggests that this is 関西弁, 博多弁, and ... 北海道弁.

Comment: amusing indeed. I guess I would say being here that 北海道弁 is more 田舎伝説 than something we hear much of in the cities, so I guess it's not surprising in the larger cities to hear people using なす